# Weird integration question

Tags: calculus

let = e(x) = $$\text{e(x) =}\int\frac{e^x}{e^x+e^{-x}}$$  and f(x) = $$\text{f(x) =}\int\frac{e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}$$

The question wants....

a) calculate e(x) + f(x)

b) calculate e(x) - f(x)

c) Use your results from parts a and b to calculates e(x) and f(x). My problem is how can you add an integrand you don't know how evaluate. You gotta evaluate the integrand first before you can. Wouldn't evaluating the integrand solve th eproblem anyway?

Comment: @DigitalBrain The question was only asked 11 minutes ago...

Comment: @Travis I'm not talking about this one

Comment: hence e(x) = ln(u) + c + f(x)? then substitute?

Comment: Digital brain sorry i though it was all about the plus ones and the check is if i know for sure it's the right answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $e(x) + f(x) = \displaystyle \int 1 dx = x$, and $e(x) - f(x) = \displaystyle \int \dfrac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}} dx = \ln(e^x + e^{-x})$

Comment: How is it ln(e^x+e-x)?

Comment: By substitution - $u=e^x+e^{-x}$. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Isn't it ln(a)-ln(b) = ln(a/b)?

Comment: Using the substitution gives that the integral is $\int \frac{du}{u} = \ln|u| + C$.

Comment: hence e(x) = ln(u) + c + f(x)? then substitute? –

Comment: I got that f(x)=(x-ln(e^x+e-x)/2 e(x)=(x+ln(e^x+e-x)/2  using substitution

Comment: thanks heaps for the help =)

Answer (score 2):

The integration is a linear operation, and therefore commutative, you can do the following:
[source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Properties ]

$$
\int (a\cdot f(x)+ b\cdot g(x)) dx = a\int f(x) dx + b\int g(x) dx
$$
Where a,b are not dependant on x.

Therefore you are able to combine your integrals.
(If you need further help, just ask)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$e(x)+f(x)=\int \frac{e^x}{e^x+e^{-x}}\,dx+\int \frac{e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}\,dx=\int \frac{e^x}{e^x+e^{-x}}+\frac{e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}\,dx=\int \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}\,dx=\int 1\,dx=x$$

Can you calculate $e(x)+f(x)$ and conclude?